# how to paste matrix of data on matrix of data in sublime text 3 (Mac)

Tags: copy-paste, sublime-text-3

my data are like this:

```
A   B   C
D   E   F
G   H   I
```

another data are like this:

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
```

result I need:

```
1A  2B  3C
4D  5E  6F
7G  8H  9I
```

I have tried command+shift+L things.
I checked the matrix both positions and tab-separated spaces.
I did regular expression for multiple editing and then pasted.

it turned out like this:

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9A  1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9B  1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9C
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9D  1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9E  1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9F
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9G  1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9H  1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9I
```

thank you in advance

Comment: You can't do that in a single step. You have to copy/paste 1 column at a time.